# How to Rotate and Translate my sprite at the same time? cocos2dx 3.2

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I tried doing **RotateBy** in update method of my sprite. It is only translating. And not rotating. Can anyone please tell me how to do it? Thank you.

```
void CBall::Update(float dt)
{
  this->Start();
  auto action = RotateBy::create(dt,10);
  this->runAction(action);
 }

void CBall::Start()
{


  float currentX = getPositionX();
  float distance =  currentX + xOffset;
  float time = distance / _speedX;



  Vec2 destination = Vec2(distance,this->getPositionY());
  auto actionMove =  MoveTo::create(time,destination);
  this->runAction(actionMove);

  if(currentX > _screenWidth)
  {
        ReachedEndOfScreen();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to use a [**Spawn action**](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/dc/df1/classcocos2d_1_1_spawn.html) it will run many actions at the same time.

Here is a modified Update Function:

```
void CBall::Update(float dt)
{

  float currentX = getPositionX();
  float distance =  currentX + xOffset;
  float time = distance / _speedX;



  Vec2 destination = Vec2(distance,this->getPositionY());
  auto actionMove =  MoveTo::create(time,destination);

  if(currentX > _screenWidth)
  {
        ReachedEndOfScreen();
  }
  auto actionRotate = RotateBy::create(dt,10);
  this->runAction(Spawn::create(actionMove, actionRotate, nullptr));
 }
```

I inlined the Start() member function you may consider to reorganize the Update implementation in a composed function ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Actually I was going to put some more things in both the methods, hence the separate methods. But anyway, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the other action in update method,try applying it with first action. Also increase the angle and decrease the duration of RotateBy action for testing.

```
float currentX = getPositionX();
float distance =  currentX + xOffset;
float time = distance / _speedX;
Vec2 destination = Vec2(distance,this->getPositionY());

auto actionMove =  MoveTo::create(time,destination);
this->runAction(actionMove);

auto action = RotateBy::create(4,720);
this->runAction(action);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It's still not working for me. I think those two are atomic. You run one after the other. And intuitively even Sequence will do the same. I want to interleave two actions. Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. However, I am using these two simultaneously in cocos2d-x 3.1

Comment: Mohak's answer should work. Are you still calling RotateBy inside update function? I don't think it is a good idea. Try to put in Start function instead